# Why do I get errors when trying to compile a multi-file project?

Tags: c++, function

The task is to separate the program into 2 .cpp files (main function and my own function) and 1 .h file.

Here is the main() function:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
const int rows = 9;
const int cols = 9;

int ARR[rows][cols];

int dirf(const int rows, const int cols, int ARR);

cin.clear();
cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');
cin.get();

return 0;
}
```

Here is my function dirf():

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

int dirf(const int rows, const int cols, int ARR)
{
// Initialize the array to 0 values to detect unmodified slots
for (int(&rows)[cols] : ARR) {
    for (int& val : rows) {
        val = 0;
    }
}

// Use symbols for directions
enum Dir
{
    left = 0,
    down,
    up,
    right,
}
dir = left;

// Define the starting point and starting value
int x = rows / 2;
int y = cols / 2;
int val = 1;

// A flag to know when to stop
bool stop = false;

// Start
for (;;)
{
    ARR[x][y] = val++;
    switch (dir)
    {
    case left:
        y -= 1;
        if (y < 0) stop = true;
        else if (ARR[x + 1][y] == 0) dir = down;
        break;
    case down:
        x += 1;
        if (x > rows) stop = true;
        else if (ARR[x][y + 1] == 0) dir = right;
        break;
    case right:
        y += 1;
        if (y >= rows) stop = true;
        else if (ARR[x - 1][y] == 0) dir = up;
        break;
    case up:
        x -= 1;
        if (x < 0) stop = true;
        else if (ARR[x][y - 1] == 0) dir = left;
    }
    if (stop) break;
}

// Display the values
for (int(&rows)[cols] : ARR) {
    for (int val : rows) {
        cout << setw(3) << val;
    }
    cout << '\n';
}
}
```

And here is .h file:

```
int dirf(const int rows, const int cols, int ARR);
```

I get many errors that say "expression must have pointer-to-object type" and some others. However, when it was a single program - everything was OK.
Where do I make mistakes?

Help me fix it.

Comment: Since you didn't `#include`d your header to *main.cpp* this cannot work.

Comment: @bloody another error: cannot open the file dirf.h